# Is there any NATIVE disk monitoring solution for storage in Azure VMs?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, monitoring, storage

I have done plenty of digging, but it looks like this may be a shortcoming in Azure.  I cannot find a native solution in the Azure portal to tell me when VMs are running low on disk space. What if I want to simply run inventory on my VMs to see how much space is being used on any attached drives? Nope.

For now I am piggy-backing on my 3rd party server monitoring agent for this, but in my situation it is less than ideal. I'm looking for something that I can use in Azure itself, it that is possible.  The best I can find in regards to a native solution is the Portal's metrics, which is more centered around performance rather than inventory so I'm still searching.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/disks-metrics

Thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: you looking for a monitoring system, imho. like monit, Nagios or similar, however this kind of requests are off-topic due product requests... Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly.

Comment: Check this answer at Stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68482941/how-to-create-azure-monitor-alert-when-my-disk-space-low-in-virtual-machine

Comment: @djdomi
Please re-read the question.  I already have a monitoring system. I am looking for a NATIVE solution in Azure.  Thanks anyway though.

Comment: @JevgenijMartynenko Thank you, that is sort of what I am looking for.  Not as polished as I would have hoped for, but a small step in the right direction.